# Tuareg-mode and caml-mode

Tags: emacs, annotations, ocaml, tuareg

I'm currently using tuareg-mode but I would like to be able to use the functionality of caml-mode as well. In particular I want to be able to use type annotations interactively, and apparently this occurs with caml-types. I tried putting http://cristal.inria.fr/~remy/poly/emacs/index.html in my .emacs.d, but I'm confused about how or if these two modes can work together. In fact, I can't get caml-mode to work at all.

I have this line in my init.el:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/modes/caml")
```

But the files are not loaded - at least, none of the function definitions or keybindings are. I really thought I was starting to grasp how these emacs plugins work, but I'm starting to wonder. Maybe someone can explain what else needs to happen?

Edit: I didn't realize I had to `require 'caml` for this to work. Still, annotations don't seem to be working although I have caml-types from http://caml.inria.fr/svn/ocaml/branches/gadts/emacs/. I compile with `-annot` but I'm still told there's no annotations file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have type annotation with the tuareg mode.
If I have this exact ~/.emacs file:

```
(add-hook 'tuareg-mode-hook '(lambda ()
  (define-key tuareg-mode-map [f10] 'caml-types-show-type); requires caml-types
  ))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.ml\\w?" . tuareg-mode))
(autoload 'caml-types-show-type "caml-types" "Show the type of expression or pattern at point." t)
```

then pressing `F10` shows the type of the expression under the point.
As you know, you need to compile your file `foo.ml` with

```
ocamlc -annot foo.ml
```

so that there is a file `foo.annot` in the same directory as `foo.ml`.

Comment: Thanks, this works. But I tried binding to "C-c C-t" without success. Is there a special format for specifying keys in define-key?

Comment: "C-c C-t" works here as well, with this minimal .emacs, without having to define it.

Comment: Well it looks like everything works as it should as long as `tuareg-with-caml-mode-p` is non-nil - when is that supposed to be enabled? I feel like I shouldn't have to do it myself. eh.

Comment: By my reading of `tuareg.el`, you should not need to tweak `tuareg-with-camp-mode-p` by hand.  Rather, `tuareg-with-camp-mode-p` should be enabled automatically if both `caml-types` and `caml-help` can be found in the load path when `tuareg` is loaded.